# Add coupon code only if all products are in specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have magento installation on it I want to apply coupon code with following conditions:

1. Cart Total is >= 500
2. Product Category is only 92 (no product from any other category should be in cart)

**Problem is coupon code is still applicable if product with any other category is in cart.**

My coupon page screenshot is as follows:
[image]

Comment: And where is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that coupon code is still applied if any other category is in cart.

Comment: you configured it like that: "if **any** item in the cart has category 92, ..."

Comment: I need only the items from category 92 in the cart else invalid coupon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then check additionally, "if an item is **NOT FOUND** in the cart with [...] Category **is not 92**":

[image: screenshot]